# Can discipline on a professional medical license be expunged if it is 25 years old?

Tags: licensing, medical

I voluntarily surrendered a nursing license 25 years ago because of substance use. I was licensed 5 years ago in a different state that I moved to after extensive investigation by the board of nursing in this state. The previous state still lists disciplinary action when my license is checked. How would I/ could I have this deleted. The board of nursing for that state says they have no paperwork related to the case.

Comment: States vary, there isn't a uniform rule.